# Requirements for a Good Chef

Tags: resources, restaurant

I'm an amateur cook and an aspiring Culinary Manager. I'm almost done with my program and I'll be opening my restaurant soon. I'll be hiring soon so I wanted to know what are the certain requirements that make a chef great. What differentiates a great chef from the mediocre chefs in the field. Please Note: I'm not fishing for resumes I'm just a curious manager looking for a good chef.

Comment: I'm about 90% sure this is probably going down as off-topic or primarily opinion based. I'll grant you a pass on the incorrect word usage on the guess that english is not your first language (an armature is the central part of an electric motor, and aspiring is a bit different than inspiring.) But mainly, I would suggest that you spend sometime **between** being a non-professional and graduating from school and "opening your restaurant" actually working as a professional chef in someone else's **successful** restaurant. It would increase the odds of your's succeeding many-fold.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's not clear that the program he's currently is training him to cook food professionally or manage restaurants. Either way though, as you suggest, obtaining practical experience as an employee in the field he's training for would be a very good idea.

Comment: It also might help him to learn to recognize what qualities he would value most in an employee and in a chef.

Comment: @Ecnerwal If you see word usage mistakes, please just edit - it takes less time than it does to point out the problem, and it's more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Quality control of food**

A good chef should be able to explain what his/her methods are for controlling food quality and determining whether the price is appropriate for the quality delivered.

**Inventory control**

A good chef should have an understanding of the inventory required to serve the expected guests. He/she should be able to talk about methods how to make sure that you don't run out of items you need or throw too much food away.

**Menu price**

A good chef should be able to calculate the price for a menu.

**Composition**

A good chef has a thorough understanding that the eye is as important as the tongue, when serving meals.

**Food safety**
A good chef knows that food safety comes before profit. You could try this with a trick question like:"You have made the last four Kobe beef steaks for four guests, but the waiter dropped the plates just before leaving the kitchen. How do you save the situation?"